# Laravel: update issue while customer has multiple records

Tags: laravel, record

I have these three tables `device_companies`, `devices` & `device_inventory` connected with relations and loaded with ajax while creating and updating a customer. However, only available data is loaded which is managed by `subscriber_devices` table.

The `create` part its working as required. But, while updating all the `devices` associated with the selected customer are loading. For example: if a `customer` has `ABC -> DEF -> A1,A2,A3` and I am updating the details of `A2` then `A1,A3` must not appear in the dropdown. Only `A2` and `A4,A5,A6,...` should load.

*Tables:*

```
device_companies:  ->  devices:                ->  device_inventories:
|-- id                 |-- id                      |-- id
|-- title              |-- device_company_id       |-- device_id
...                    |-- title                   |-- serial_number
                       ...                         ...

subscriber_devices:
|-- id
|-- subscriber_id
|-- device_inventory_id
...
```

*DeviceCompany:*

```php
public function devices()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Device::class);
}

public function _dropdown($useWith = null, $subscriber = null)
{
  $Self = self::where('status', \Common::STATUS_ACTIVE)->select([
    'id',
    'title'
  ])->orderBy('title', 'ASC');

  # with relations
  if($useWith == true)
    $Self = $Self->whereHas('devices.deviceInventory', function($q) use ($subscriber) {
      $q->whereDoesntHave('subscriberDevice', function($q) use ($subscriber) {
        if(!is_null($subscriber))
          $q->where('subscriber_id', '!=', $subscriber->subscriber_id);
      });
    });

  # building query
  $Self = $Self->get();

  return ($Self->isEmpty() == false)
    ? $Self->toArray()
    : null;
}
```

*Device:*

```php
public function deviceCompany()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(DeviceCompany::class);
}

public function deviceInventory()
{
  return $this
    ->hasMany(DeviceInventory::class)
    ->where('status', \Common::STATUS_ACTIVE)
    ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC');
}

public function _dropdown($deviceCompanyId, $useWith = null, $subscriber = null)
{
  $Self = self::select([ 'id', 'title' ])->where([
    'device_company_id' => $deviceCompanyId,
    'status'            => \Common::STATUS_ACTIVE
  ])->orderBy('title', 'ASC');

  # with relation
  if($useWith == true)
    $Self = $Self->whereHas('deviceInventory', function($q) use ($subscriber) {
      $q->whereDoesntHave('subscriberDevice', function($q) use ($subscriber) {
        if(!is_null($subscriber))
          $q->where('subscriber_id', '!=', $subscriber->subscriber_id);
        });
    });

  # building query
  $Self = $Self->get();

  return ($Self->isEmpty() == false)
    ? $Self->toArray()
    : null;
}
```

*DeviceInventory:*

```php
public function subscriberDevice()
{
  return $this->hasOne(SubscriberDevice::class);
}

public function _dropdown($deviceId, $useWith = null, $subscriber = null)
{
  $Self = self::select([
    'id',
    'serial_number AS title'
  ])->where([
    'device_id' => $deviceId,
    'status'    => \Common::STATUS_ACTIVE
  ])->orderBy('title', 'ASC');

  # with relations
  if($useWith == true)
    $Self = $Self->whereDoesntHave('subscriberDevice', function($q) use ($subscriber) {
      if(!is_null($subscriber))
        $q->where('subscriber_id', '!=', $subscriber->subscriber_id);
    });

  # building query
  $Self = $Self->get();

  return ($Self->isEmpty() == false)
    ? $Self->toArray()
    : null;
}
```

*SubscriberDevice:*

```php
public function subscriber()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Subscriber::class);
}
public function deviceInventory()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(DeviceInventory::class);
}
```

*Response (current):*

```
{
    0: "-- Device Inventory --",
    1: "A1",
    2: "A2",
    3: "A3",
    4: "A4",
    5: "A5",
    6: "A6",
}
```

The current user has three `inventories` associated with him `A1, A2 & A3`.
The `inventory` selected to edit is `A2`.
The `A4, A5 & A6` are available `inventories` which can be selected.

*Therefore, the expected result is:*

```
{
    0: "-- Device Inventory --",
    2: "A2",
    4: "A4",
    5: "A5",
    6: "A6",
}
```

Comment: Please share the current json response vs the expected json response

Comment: @ChristopheHubert, I have added the current and expected response, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it took me a while. But, I solved the problem. Here is my final code...

```php
public function _dropdown($deviceId, $useWith = null, $subscriber = null)
{
  ...

  # with relations
  if($useWith == true)
    $Self = $Self->whereDoesntHave('subscriberDevice', function($q) use ($subscriber) {
      if(!is_null($subscriber))
        $query->where('token', '!=', $subscriber->token);
    });

  ...
}
```

It turns out the only thing that needed to changed was the `where` condition's column from `subscriber_id` to `token`. The `token` is a unique identifier of the subscriber's `inventory` record which was being edited.

Hope this may someone with the similar problem.